# SAML 2.0 AuthnRequest AudienceRestriction

Tags: saml, opensso

During a AuthnRequest, is there a case where the AudienceRestriction

```
<saml:AudienceRestriction>
  <saml:Audience>http://serviceprovider.com/</saml:Audience>
</saml:AudienceRestriction>
```

would be different from the Issuer in the AuthnRequest

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <saml2p:AuthnRequest 
       xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
       xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
       xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
       AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://serviceprovider.com/acs/web/sso/receiveSamlAuthentication" 
      Destination="http://idp.net/idp/SSOPOST/metaAlias/realm2/IDP"
     ID="http://serviceprovider.com/acsdata/data/AcsConfiguration/821212" IssueInstant="2010-08-20T14:48:27.620Z" Version="2.0">
              <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://serviceprovider.com/</saml2:Issuer>
....
   </saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAML 2.0 Web Browser SSO Profile (from saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf:566/577):

> The assertion(s) containing a bearer
>   subject confirmation MUST contain an
>   AudienceRestriction including the
>   service provider's unique identifier
>   as an Audience

So, it seems as though it should always be the case that they are the same, at least to be conformant to the published profile.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you have one login application at one URL, and a "real" application at a different URL? Maybe not common, but hardly impossible; say, having login functionality over HTTPS and the application over HTTP.